# Firefox goes blank when zooming

Tags: firefox, zooming

See http://www.randstad.nl/ and https://www.tempo-team.nl/

When you zoom in or out on firefox, the screen goes blank.
Sometimes it still shows some words or a bit of styling.

I have no idea where to start looking.

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have fixed it.

Apparently it had something to do with a hidden element, with an animation that had a fixed position.

When I removed the fixed position, all seems to work well. I hope this helps someone that has the same problem.